# Laravel Eloquent Query absence through shared relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a relationship like this

#### Requests

```
=> id

public function proposals(){
    return $this->hasMany(Proposal::class)
}
```

#### Proposals

```
=> request_id
=> company_id

public function request(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Request::class)
}

public function proposals(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class)
}
```

#### Companies

```
=> id

public function proposals(){
    return $this->hasMany(Proposal::class)
}
```

I've tought in something like this:

```
$request->with('proposals')->whereDoesntHave('company', function($query){
    $query->where('company_id', '<>', 1);
})->get()
```

But it didn't work out.

In this scenario how can I retrieve all the **requests** that one **company** has not sent a proposal?

#### EDIT

A short version of my DB Schema[image]

A **User** can have many **Companies**, a **User** can make **Requests**, a **Company** respond to this **Request** through a **Proposal**

Comment: Your relationships don't look right to me. It seems like you have a many-many relationship between Company and Request and, with your Proposal being the pivot table, is that correct?

Comment: Nope. I have a Request table, and one request can have many Proposals, and each proposal is made by one Company. So one company can have many proposals. And a Company cannot make more than one proposal to a single request.

Comment: Filipe, you've just described the many-many relationship I mentioned. A Request can have many Proposals, a Company can have many Proposals. And a single Proposal belongs to one Request and one Company. If that's correct, then your relationship models are wrong (and maybe your DB structure, which we haven't seen). Can you add your DB structure?

Comment: @Jason I've updated my question with my DB Schema

Answer (score 0):

What I am seeing here from your schema is a pivot table relationship.

A **Request** can belong to many **Companies**, and a **Company** can have many **Requests**. The relationship between the two is the **Proposal**, which is your pivot table.

So firstly, you want add the correct relationships to your models

```php
class Request
{
    public function companies()
    {
        // You will need to probably set the foreign and local keys as extra parameters here
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'proposals')->using(Proposal::class);
    }
}
```

and

```php
class Company
{
    public function requests()
    {
        // You will need to probably set the foreign and local keys as extra parameters here
        return $this->belongsToMany(Request::class, 'proposals')->using(Proposal::class);
    }
}
```

Finally, you can get the proposal using the pivot which will be a Proposal object.

To address your original query, you would just do:

```php
$requests = Request::with(['companies' => function($q) {
    $q->where('companyid', '!=', 1);
}]);
```